# Do all entities in Chen notation have to be diagrammatically linked?

Tags: database-design, erd

Is it good design practice to visually link each entity when using Chen's notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, Chen though so and explicitly calls for it his 1976, and 2002 papers. From his 1976 paper, [*The Entity-Relationship Model-Toward a
Unified View of Data*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fdc8/b4381a3d9e81d308ac7c37a6cddde567383d.pdf).

[image: 1976 paper]

From his paper, [*Entity-Relationship Modeling: Historical Events, Future Trends, and Lessons Learned* 2002](http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~chen/pdf/Chen_Pioneers.pdf)

> **ER Model has Explicit Linkage between Entities.** As can be seen in Figures 2 and 4, the linkage between
>   entities is explicit in the ER model while in the relational model is implicit. In addition, the cardinality
>   information is explicit in the ER model, and some of the cardinality information is not captured in the
>   relational model.

Here is Figure 2,

[image: Figure 2 from chen's paper]

His contemporaries that cite him also seem to be using explicit links  [Hartmann, Sven. *"Reasoning about participation constraints and Chen's constraints".*  Proceedings of the 14th Australasian database conference-Volume 17. Australian Computer Society, Inc., 2003.](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV17Hartmann.pdf)

[image: Chen's ERD]

Without the links, you have no relationship. It's a dangling entity.